# Open custom links in UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview

I have an application that shows presentations that are composed by pages.

Those pages can contain some kinds of media, and one of them is HTML, wich uses an UIWebView component as viewer.

What I need is some way to insert some kind of link into the HTML document so I can jump to another page of my application presentation.

In my research I have found that subclassing UIWebView is not recommended, so I have no clue of how I should handle this.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide:

```
-webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:
```

in your app delegate ([ref here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webView%3ashouldStartLoadWithRequest%3anavigationType%3a)).

It will be called each time the web view is about to load new content and give you the chance to do what you need. E.g., this would work if you embed a "file://" kind of URL in your web page:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    if ([[[request URL] scheme] isEqual:@"file"])
        return YES;
    ...
```